# Using the created document trough FPDF with PHP/JAVA

Tags: java, php, printing, fpdf, silent

I created a PDF document with PHP using FPDF. The next thing I want to do is silently printing the document without downloading the PDF file to the computer.

I've made the following code:

```
$pdfprintable = $pdf->Output(''.'.pdf','S');
$printcmd = "java -classpath jPDFPrint.jar;pdfprintcli.jar cli.PDFPrintCLI $pdfprintable";
exec($printcmd);
```

And it returns the following error message:

> Warning: exec(): NULL byte detected. Possible attack in C:\Users\Jordy\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\php\stickers\pdf.php on line 392

If I echo the `$pdfprintable` in PHP it shows a lot of weird characters.

Comment: Nothing wrong with FPDF $pdfprintable. You are trying to return the string reppresantation of the PDF and that is what it is

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the java command is supposed to be used with an hexadecimal string represenation of the  PDF ?

use option

```
$pdfprintable = $pdf->Output('USEAFULLPATHTOFILE.pdf','F');
```

With the above the PDF is generated and then you can try to print it with the java application if that one works.

Also if you are loading the PDF correctly in FPDF you should be able to use the option D in ->Output

`$pdfprintable = $pdf->Output('USEAFULLPATHTOFILE.pdf','D');`

Use this to verify the that the PDF is loaded and also managed correctly by FPDF. 
Also notice your example code is very limited. 
If you need more troubleshooting pls show the Java and the full PHP source relevant to printing operation, loading or creation of the PDF in FPDF

Comment: When is use 'F' instead pf 'S' the script will download a file into my directory. The script will be used by multiple people at the same time and every time i run the script the file gets updated. This is not going to work with multiple users at the same moment.

Comment: The above is an answer on what I think you should do to debug your solution. Unless you share your full codebase and the java source is impossible to guess what is happening. The options in my answers are related to your question of why you see a sequence of characters. When running with the S option you see a string reppresentation of the PDF, there is nothing wrong with that. The problem is most likely in your java or in the fact that its input must be the file, hence I was suggesting the use of the file as an input instead of the string. I hope this helps